# Arguments are not being passed when calling task from stream on cloud dataflow

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to launch my componse-task from a stream however i am unable to pass information down to the task itself.

This is my code so far in the stream app

```java
      Map<String, String> environmentProperties = new HashMap<>();
      environmentProperties.put("graph", "my-composed-task");


      List<String> commandLineParameter = new ArrayList<>();
      commandLineParameter.add("--increment-instance-enabled=true");

      Map<String, String> deploymentProperties = new HashMap<>();

      TaskLaunchRequest taskLaunchRequest = new TaskLaunchRequest(
                    springCloudHttpSourceProperties.getUri(),
                    commandLineParameter,
                    environmentProperties,
                    deploymentProperties,
                    springCloudHttpSourceProperties.getTaskName()
       );

       log.info("" + taskLaunchRequest);

       this.sink.input().send(new GenericMessage<>(taskLaunchRequest));
```

The graph property seems to work just fine however the --increment-instance-enabled command line does not seem to go through.

On my server log i can see the call being made without the  command line paramenter:

```
Co.s.c.d.spi.local.LocalTaskLauncher: Command to be executed: /opt/openjdk/bin/java -jar /root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/task/app/composedtaskrunner-task/2.0.2.RELEASE/composedtaskrunner-task-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar --spring.cloud.task.executionid=1
```

But for instance if i lauch this task using the shell or using the UI itself 
using the command:

```
task launch my-composed-task --arguments "--increment-instance-enabled=true"
```

everything seems to be passed on:

```
Co.s.c.d.spi.local.LocalTaskLauncher: Command to be executed: /opt/openjdk/bin/java -jar /root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/task/app/composedtaskrunner-task/2.0.2.RELEASE/composedtaskrunner-task-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar --increment-instance-enabled=true --spring.cloud.task.executionid=1
```

I am using 2.0.2.RELEASE of composedtaskrunner jar.

Am i doing something wrong or there is a bug in cloudflow that i am not aware of?

Comment: What task-launcher are you using?

Comment: I am using an APP type stream that is lauching the tasks itself by being annotated with @EnableTaskLauncher.  Version 2.0.0.RELEASE of spring-cloud-starter-task